# Find the partial fraction: $\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning, partial-fractions

I'm trying to find the partial fraction for the following $\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)}$ by the process of long-division, here's what I have tried:

Leaving $(x-3)$ as it is in the denominator and aiming for $(x-1)$ and $(x-2)$.

First step:
$\frac{1^2}{(x-1)^2(1-2)^2(1-3)} = \frac{1}{-2(x-1)^2}, \frac{2^2}{(2-1)^2(x-2)^2(2-3)} = \frac{4}{-(x-2)^2}$

We should then substract this from the first equation to get:

$\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)} - \frac{1}{-2(x-1)^2} - \frac{4}{-(x-2)^2} = \frac{9x^3-36-45x^2+72x}{2\left(x-1\right)^2\left(x-2\right)^2\left(x-3\right)}$

Taking synthetic division on the numerator I find that 2 and 3 is not a root as there exists remainders. Have I approached this step in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made some error in your simplification.

$$
\frac{x^2}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)} - \frac{1}{-2(x-1)^2} - \frac{4}{-(x-2)^2}$$
$$
\begin{align*}
&= \frac{x^2+\frac12(x-2)^2(x-3)+4(x-1)^2(x-3)}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)} \\
&= \frac{9x^3-45x^2+72x-36}{2(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)} \\[1ex]
&= \frac{9(x^3-5x^2+8x-4)}{2(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)} \\[1ex]
&= \frac{9(x-1)(x-2)^2}{2(x-1)^2(x-2)^2(x-3)} \\[1ex]
&= \frac{9}{2(x-1)(x-3)}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I think you're right and after applying the partial fraction again I got the answer. Think I was slightly thrown off by the lack of practice! Though I feel better cemented towards these now

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $f(x) = \dfrac{A}{x-1}+\dfrac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\dfrac{C}{x-2}+\dfrac{D}{(x-2)^2}+\dfrac{E}{x-3}$. And you have to find these constants $A,B,C,D,E$.

Comment: I know this approach although I was aiming for the approach that involves synthetic division just for practice reasons

Comment: I disagree with your answer. Since there are two denominators of degree $2$ the numerator must be $B=ax+b$ instead of $B$. The same for $D$. The only real constants are $A, C$ and $E$.

Comment: @Sebastiano $$\frac A{x-1} + \frac B{(x-1)^2} = \frac{A(x-1) + B}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{ax+b}{(x-1)^2}$$where $a=A$ and $b=B-A$

Comment: @user170231 I agree with you at the 100 %. +1 for the comment.....and....

Comment: Just to be clear, my point is that there's no need to expand as$$\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{ax+b}{(x-1)^2}$$ because a part of the $\frac{ax}{(x-1)^2}$ gets absorbed into the $\frac A{x-1}$ term.$$\frac{ax+b}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{a(x-1)+a}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{b}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{a}{x-1}+\frac{a+b}{(x-1)^2}$$so the decomposition proposed by Wang is perfectly acceptable.